# How to see the app version after installed it on IOS device from App Center?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, ipa, visual-studio-app-center

On [Microsoft App Center](https://appcenter.ms/) how can I see the version of the installed app on an IOS device?
I already checked the docs but I couldn't find anything, so not sure if that's even possible.

**OBS:** I'm creating App Center releases from a React Native app using the .ipa file.

Comment: Do you want see it at runtime or you just have a .ipa file, and you want to find a file that records version information?

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to know which AppCenter release version I installed on my device.